# Clairification on picklist values and profiles

Tags: salesforce

I'm new to Salesforce and I want to make sure I understand Profiles and Picklist values.

## Setup

My company has a ton of profiles. For a picklist field in the contacts object, they want to add a couple of choices.

## Issue

I want to make sure that the choices I add to the PL are availible to all profiles. When I go to add the option for the PL I don't select any of the options for
" To add the new value to the picklist values for a particular Record Type, check the appropriate boxes below. "

## Questions

1. By not selecting anything, am I guaranteed that the option will show up for all profiles? (I'm pretty sure about this)
2. Say that there are some profiles that can't access this field, what happens then? Does it work that if  and only if the profile can see the field then they can see the values I added?

Thanks, 
-el noobre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Profiles don't matter for the values.  Just whether they can see the field or not.  What does matter is record types.  For a given record type some or all of the primary fields picklist values can be made available.

So if you add a new value to the picklist field you can be sure all profiles can see it.  Again what matters is the record type, not the profile.

I'm not sure I understand the seconde question.  If they don't have visibility to the field it doesn't exist as far as they're concerned.  Why would it matter what values the picklist had?